# Is there a Groovy way of making a method synchronized?

Tags: groovy

I'm working with Groovy 1.7.2. There are methods which needs to be Synchronized , is there any groovier way of doing this or I have to follow same Java way of putting `synchronized` keyword before method.

```
e.g : synchronized static def  Map getMap(def fileName) { }
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you can upgrade to Groovy 1.7.3 you can use the `Synchronized` AST transformation instead. You can use the annotation on instance and static methods. The annotation will create a lock variable in your class (or you can use an existing variable) and the code is synchronized on that lock variable.

The usage of a `synchronized` block should be preferred over adding the keyword to the method. If you use the `synchronized` keyword on the method you synchronize on `this` which means that all other threads that want to access any of the methods in your class have to wait until the lock is free again.

```
import groovy.transform.Synchronized

class YourClass {
    @Synchronized
    static Map getMap(def fileName) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: the upgrade is not plan for now,but the information is provided definitely very helpful, it means in groovy 1.7.2 i can use java synchronized style ,

Answer (score 2):

Since **Groovy 1.7.3** we have a new AST transformation: [**@Synchronized**](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/2.4.7/html/gapi/groovy/transform/Synchronized.html)